# how to make c# texbox take unicode characters as a character of size 1

Tags: c#, unicode, character

I have a textbox control in a c#.net project (ASP.Net) , which accepts 50 characters on it. If I  add  a unicode heart (♥) symbol it will take around 4 character size , so the validation is not correctly fired. For eg if i type 49 characters and one unicode heart(♥) in the textbox the validation fires as "You entered more than 50 characters in the textbox", My question is there any method in C# to treat unicode characters (like ♥) as a single character , or can anyone tell me how we can handle such a situation.. ???Please help

Comment: How have you implemented your validation? MVC Data Annotations?

Comment: Is it the server-side or the client-side validation?

Comment: if you're using a `char`, that's not possible, since a `char` only holds 1 Byte (= 8 bit) of data, whereas Unicode can go up to 4 Bytes (= 32 bit)

Comment: +RB just checking the count of the  string in the textbox > 50 thats all

Comment: its a client side validatoin in javascript

Comment: Can you post some code as to what you have tried?. If I understand your question, you can override the keyDown or KeyPress events of your text box and parse the Text property string for the unicode character,

Comment: If the validation is done on the server, then the server should check for the special characters not the client

Comment: Actually i want to accept the special characters like heart ♥. the issue is with the count only , i just need the control to accept just 50 characters if it is unicode or not ..

Comment: @Nolonar: A char in C# occupies 2 bytes, not 1 (since it is UTF16)

Comment: C# TextBox controls *do* use Unicode. (In fact they use UTF16). If you do TextBox.Text.Length, it should be returning the actual length in chars. What is the validation actually using? It must be something else.

Comment: @Nolonar No, a `char` in C# and .NET is a 16-bit type, somewhat like `ushort`. Any Unicode character up to U+FFFF can be held in _one_ `char` value. Later Unicode characters need to use surrogate pairs (two `char` make up one Unicode character) in the same way as in UTF-16.

Comment: @MatthewWatson actually validation is for limit the string length in 50 . but if a unicode character comes after entering 49 characters it will flag error naturally, but the user takes a unicode also as a single character right ?

Comment: I don't really understand why it's not working. The validation should, I would have  thought, use string.Length to check the number of entered characters - in which case, it should work because string.Length counts actual characters (counting extended unicode characters that occupy more than 2 bytes as a single character).

Comment: @MatthewWatson  u r absolutely correct , script counts the exact characters .. that/s exactly my problem is. the validation can only accept 50 characters.If we enter 49 characters (like a,b,c n, etc) and a single unicode like ♥, now the count has become greater than 50 , which wont go thro the validation ...   any idea ??

Comment: Show the code... `♥` in a C# string will count as 1 character.. even if you were counting bytes, there is no encoding where `♥` takes 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using html encoding somewhere, that turns it into `&heart;` or `#9829;` or similar, please use basic debugging to find out. The literal `♥` character is just like any other character like `a` or `b` - it will count as 1 character or `char`.

You could also be counting the form encoded characters, where ♥ is encoded as `"%E2%99%A5"` (9 characters)